# Ipify bloqueado por Cors cuando uso un HttpInterceptor

Tags: javascript

mi problema es el siguiente, estoy realizando un interceptor para la autenticación JWT en angular, pero al usar este me genera el siguiente error en ipify.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Hay alguna manera de evitar que el interceptor no afecte a ipify?

```
public getIpAddress(){
    return this.https.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza HttpContext(), debes omitir el envio del Token a esa solicitud, y con HttpContext() puedes hacerlo, funciona para version 12.0 o posterior de angular:

//En el interceptor seria asi:

````
export const BYPASS_JW_TOKEN = new HttpContextToken(() => false);

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class InterceptorServiceService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headers= new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
    });

    const reqClone=req.clone({
      headers
    });

    if (req.context.get(BYPASS_JW_TOKEN) === true) {
      return next.handle(req)
    }
    return next.handle(reqClone);
  }

}

//En el servicio o Solicitud seria asi:
import { BYPASS_JW_TOKEN } from '../interceptors/interceptor-service.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IpServiceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getIPAddress(){
    return this.http.get('http://api.ipify.org?format=json',{
      context: new HttpContext().set(BYPASS_JW_TOKEN, true)
    });
  }
}```

//En resumen, se esta omitiendo el envio del Token para esa solicitud o para varios servicios donde no quieras enviar el token con el interceptor
````